# MS Visual Studio.net - saved source files missing after reboot

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The other day I created a MS visual studio 2010 C# project and started coding. I saved the source frequently, but I did not select a destination to save to (just pressed ctrl+s and assumed the source was being saved). However I had to run and threw my laptop in my backpack on sleep. Unfortunately this laptop (acer aspire 5252 fyi) battery drains extremely quickly when on sleep, and eventually my computer shut off. Now I can't find my source files anywhere and I'm going crazy because I know I saved it and it's several days worth of work.

I tried doing a windows search but couldn't find the project files. I also did a little experiment - I created a new project and without saving the entire solution, I pressed ctrl+s on the source files. Save was successful, but I cannot even find the file that's open in the IDE. Even the "open containing folder option" is grayed out (see screen shot).

[image: File was created and saved, but where is it?]

I really need these source files back. Obviously it's because I didn't save the solution that the source got wiped out, but where do the source files get saved temporarily before the solution is saved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Visual Studio's support for temporary projects.  Nice feature for quicky test projects (and SO answers) but not a great way to ensure that your projects are still there after VS quits.  Programming without source control is similarly inadvisable.

Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, General.  Ensure that the "Save new projects when created" option is ticked to minimize the odds that you'll forget to pick a solution folder.  Triple-check that creating a new project now gives you a "Location" property in the dialog.

Comment: Alright. I guess that's the least I can do at this point. Curse you Microsoft and Acer!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a **default location** for projects to be saved. That is probably where your files went.

In Visual Studio, on the menu, click Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General. There is a "Visual Studio projects location".

On my Windows 7 machine, the folder for Visual Studio 2010 is

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects
```

Your unnamed project is probably saved with a default name like WebSite1.

If you would like to [change that default location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/34c29fes%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), here is some information on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, that's where I assumed it would be saved originally, but it's not there :S. I also tried looking for hidden files/folders in this path.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio temporary projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yx39k28.aspx) are normally found in  ***C:\Users\"User Name"\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects*** . It is a temporary folder that is deleted as soon as Visual Studio starts up.

How to save a Temporay Project from above link:

### To save a temporary project

1. In Solution Explorer, choose the solution or project that you want to save.
2. On the menu bar, choose File, Save or Save As.
   The Save Project dialog box opens.
3. In the , Name box, specify a name for the project.
4. In the Location box, specify where you want to save the project.
5. Select the Create directory for Solution check box.
   Note: This check box is not available for Visual Basic web projects, Visual C# web projects, or other directory-based projects.
6. In the New Solution Name box, specify a name that differs from the project name.
7. Select the Add to Source Control check box if you want to add the solution to a version-control database or repository.
8. Choose the OK button.